# How do I create a set of options to choose how many posts per page and what page to view on a blog

Tags: php, blogs

This seems to be the simplest thing in the world to do, yet I'm failing, probably because of math. Anyhow, my situation is this:

In my programming in PHP course I've assigned myself to do a blog with all the normal bells and whistles. I've come a short way but have already run into a problem which I'm sure has been solved at least a dozen times, but my Google mojo fails to find me a solution.

So here is what I want to do: I want to have a number of links on the page which lets the user choose the number of blog posts shown on each page along with links changing which page the user is on.

Here is the page I'm working on, it's in Swedish but you get the idea, the links are at the bottom: http://lamp.skola.skelleftea.se/~matste/elever/christian_l/blag/index.php

And this is the code that I have written this far which fails to give the wanted result:

```
$antal = $_GET[antal];
if (!isset($antal)){
    $antal = 1;
}

$sida = $_GET[sida];
if (!isset($sida)){
     $sida = 0;
}

/*Some HTML markup here*/

$start = ($sida * $antal);
$stop = ($sida * $antal) + $antal;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `posts` ORDER BY `number` DESC LIMIT {$start},{$stop}";
$posts = mysql_query($sql);

/*The code that shows the fetched posts*/

$antalsVal = array(1, 3, 5, 10);
echo '<table class="right"> <tr>';
foreach ($antalsVal as $val){
    echo '<td style="padding:0.7em"> <a href="http://lamp.skola.skelleftea.se/~matste/elever/christian_l/blag/index.php?
    antal='. $val. '&sida='. $sida. '"> '. $val. ' </a></td>';
}
echo '<td> <h5>: Inlägg per sida</td></table>';

$sidoVal = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
echo '<table class="left"> <tr> <td> <h5>Sida: </td>';
foreach ($sidoVal as $val){
    echo '<td style="padding:0.7em"> <a href="http://lamp.skola.skelleftea.se/~matste/elever/christian_l/blag/index.php
    ?antal='. $antal. '&sida='. $val. '"> '. $val. ' </a></td>';
}
echo '</table><br /><br /><br />';

/*Some ending markup*/
```

Answer (score 0):

This is untested.  It might not be correct But try this.

If `$sida` is not set, set it to 1.

Let `$start = ($sida * $antal) - $antal`

Let `$stop = $sida * $antal`

Comment: The problem still remains that when I go to page 2, I get two posts showing instead of one. The site is now adjusted to fallow your code YWE and is showing this symptom. Sida = page, Inlägg per sida = posts per page.